# Combine two Bytes to WideChar

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, unicode-string, widechar, multibyte-functions

Is it possible to combine two `Bytes` to `WideChar` and if yes, then how?

For example, letter "ē" in binary is `00010011` = `19` and `00000001` = `1`, or `275` together.

```
var
  WChar: WideChar;
begin
  WChar := WideChar(275); // Result is "ē"
```

```
var
  B1, B2: Byte;
  WChar: WideChar;
begin
  B1 := 19;
  B2 := 1;
  WChar := CombineBytesToWideChar(B1, B2); // ???
```

How do I get `WideChar` from two bytes in Delphi?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
WChar := WideChar(MakeWord(B1, B2));
```

Comment: Ahh I forgot about MakeWord, nice :)

Answer (score 3):

You should just be able to create a type and cast:

```
type
  DoubleByte = packed record
    B1: Byte;
    B2: Byte;
  end;

var
  DB: DoubleByte;
  WC: WideChar;
begin
  DB.B1 := 19;
  DB.B2 := 1;

  WC = WideChar(DB);
end;
```

Failing a cast you can use `Move()` instead and simply copy the memory.